# insert query doesn't work sometime for some users with session variables

Tags: php, mysql, session, browser, insert

I have this query for inserting data into database.

```
mysqli_query($server,"INSERT INTO student (fname,lname,father,identification,student_number,tel,email,datetime,course_id,fee,refid) VALUES ('$_SESSION[fname]','$_SESSION[lname]','$_SESSION[father]',
'$_SESSION[identification]','$_SESSION[student_number]','$_SESSION[tel]','$_SESSION[eemail]','$datetime','$_SESSION[courseid]','$_SESSION[fee]','$result->RefID')")
```

It works for some users but it doesn't work sometimes for some other users (I guess because of version of their browsers).

Is there anything wrong with the query? Does this query work on old browsers?

Comment: FIrst of all, Query is not related to browser. It doesn't matter which browser client is using, query runs on server

Comment: It's not working because you missing ' ' in session indexes `$_SESSION['index']` escape it like `'.$_SESSION['index'].'`

Comment: Then why does it work most of the times like this '$_SESSION[index]' ?

Comment: Change and try and you will see, do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to see errors ? If you don't have turn it on and all will be clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first try to print the session variables with echo like echo $_SESSION[fname];